# How to obtain data use Classic ASP from ajax json post

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp-classic

I am trying to learn a way to send data to classic asp via ajax json
the asp page had been successfully called by json, but the issue is data unable to reach back side, therefore database is unable to modify according to revised sort

front side

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {
        alert(ui.item.index());
        alert(ui.item.attr("id"));
        var data={
            'sort':ui.item.index()
            }
        $.ajax({
              url: 'work.asp?action=update,
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              dataType: "json",
              error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                  alert(err.Message);
              },
              success: function (){
                  alert("success");
              }
        });
    }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

back side I use classic ASP
but I am unable to obtain the data in data
How can I make it?

```
    <%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DBPath = Server.MapPath("wawaaddatatable.mdb")
conn.Open "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath


if request.QueryString("action")="update" then

Response.ContentType = "application/json"

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.open "Select * From images ",conn,1,3

rs.addnew
rs("sort")=request.form("sort")
rs("upload_date")=date()
rs("filename")="abc.jpg"
rs.update
rs.close

end if
%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the request is being sent in JSON format, so when you try and get the value of "sort" it does not exist in the Request.Form collection. Although you could parse JSON and get the value I would suggest it would be easier to change the request to be sent as a normal form post instead.

I have modified your script below. Please see the comments I added within. With these changes, Request.Form("sort") will return a comma separated string of the sort order values, so your existing back-end should still work.

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {
        alert(ui.item.index());
        alert(ui.item.attr("id"));
        //following not needed now
        //var data={
        //  'sort':ui.item.index()
        //  }
        $.ajax({
              url: "work.asp?action=update", // update
              type: "POST",
              //Removed contentType so default will be used which is normal form post data
              //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              //Changed data to use this method which sends order as comma separated string
              data: { sort: $('#sortable').sortable('serialize') },
              dataType: "json",
              error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                  alert(err.Message);
              },
              success: function (){
                  alert("success");
              }
        });
    }
    });
  });
  </script>
```